# Remove last comma from JSON file in JS for consuption by Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm consuming a JSON file using Axios in my Vue app. One of the fields (country)has a trailing comma and it's causing issues.

JSON

```
 "country": "spain,france,"  
        ....
    "country": "spain,belgium,"
    ...
```

JS

I tried to replace a word using the code below and this worked fine. It replaced 'france' with 'XXXXXX'

```
const arr = this.countries;
            const newArr = arr.map((countries) => {
             if (countries === "france") {
               return "XXXXXX";
             }
          //   return countries;
             });
           console.log("commas " + newArr);
```

I have tried various ways to remove the end comma but I can't seem to work how to. Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: That appears to comma-separated values embedded in XML, not JSON. How are you reading this data?

Comment: You should be implementing JSON.parse/JSON.stringify to prevent breakage. Wrap parse/stringify with a try/catch to catch bad JSON formats. Best bet. This looks more XML than JSON to.

Comment: This looks more like a job for [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with `','` and drop the last array entry or `.replace(/,$/, '');` beforehand.

Comment: Apologies, it is a JSON file and I have amended my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this point, where you have the "country" value from your XML for e.g. in the variable countryString you could do following:

```
let countryString = "belgium,france,";

let countries = countryString.split(",").filter(e => e).map((e) => {
    if (e === "france") { return "XXXXXX"; }
    return e;
});
console.log(countries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to remove last char:

```js
let countryString = "belgium,france,";
countryString = countryString.slice(0, -1); 
console.log(countryString)
```